# Is this a correct equivalent formulation of the universal property of the polynomial ring?

Tags: proof-verification, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, universal-property

To the best of my understanding, the universal property of the polynomial ring can be phrased (see page 5 [here](http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/~aschmitt/SkriptAlgI.pdf)):

> Given a **commutative** and unital $R$, then the polynomial ring $R[X]$ satisfies the universal property that for any pair $(\phi, s)$, where $\phi: R \to S$ is a ring homomorphism, $s \in S$, and $S$ is also a **commutative** unital ring, there is a unique ring homomorphism $\Phi: R[X] \to S$ such that $\Phi(x)=s$ and $\Phi \circ \iota = \phi$, where $\iota: R \to R[X]$ is the standard inclusion.

Note that I assume ring homomorphisms preserve the multiplicative identity.

**Question:** Is the following a correct equivalent formulation?

> Given a commutative unital ring $R$, the polynomial ring $R[X]$ satisfies the universal property that for any pair $(\phi, s)$, where $\phi: R \to S$ is a ring homomorphism and $s \in S$ is such that $\sigma \cdot s = s \cdot \sigma$  for all $\sigma \in \operatorname{Im}(\phi)$, and $S$ is a unital ring (***not*** necessarily commutative), then there is a unique ring homomorphism $\Phi: R[X] \to S$ such that $\Phi(x) =s$ and $\Phi \circ \iota = \phi$, where $\iota: R \to R[X]$ is the standard inclusion.

**Motivation:** The one-to-one correspondence between (i) $R[X]$ module structures on a given abelian group $M$ compatible with a given $R$-module structure on $M$ and (ii) (abelian) group endomorphisms on $M$ which are $R$-linear with respect to the given $R$-module structure, would be a direct consequence of the second formulation. (Compare page 73 [here](http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/~aschmitt/SkriptAlgI.pdf).)

Take $S = \operatorname{End}(M)$, $\phi$ the $R$-scalar multiplication, $\Phi$ the $R[X]$-scalar multiplication, and $s$ to be the $R$-linear (w.r.t. $\phi$) endomorphism of $M$. ($s$ commuting with all $\sigma \in \operatorname{Im}(\phi)$ is what makes it $R$-linear.)

**Proof Attempt:** I'll skip details for brevity, but basically I think I was able to show that an $s \in S$ commutes with all $\sigma \in \operatorname{Im}(\phi)$ if and only if $s$ is contained in some commutative subring of $S$ which also contains $\operatorname{Im}(\phi)$.

It should hopefully also be true that every such subring contains the subring generated by $s$ and $\operatorname{Im}(\phi)$ (called $k[f]$ [on p.73 of the linked notes](http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/~aschmitt/SkriptAlgI.pdf)), and so the $\Phi$ we get by applying the standard formulation of the universal property of the polynomial ring should be the same regardless of which commutative subring of $S$ containing both $s$ and $\operatorname{Im}(\phi)$ we choose.

The other direction is trivial since obviously any $s \in S$ will satisfy the required condition when $S$ is itself commutative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this works.  The proof is basically identical to the proof for commutative rings, since the assumption that $\sigma s=s\sigma$ for all $\sigma \in \operatorname{Im}(\phi)$ means that all the elements of $S$ you will ever write down in the proof commute.  Or alternatively, as you mentioned, you can just say that the subring generated by $s$ and $\operatorname{Im}(\phi)$ is commutative and then apply the result for commutative rings.

Comment: Thank you for the sanity check! The notes I was looking at didn't mention this explicitly, so I just wanted to make sure I wasn't making up something that was too good to be true. It took me a while to figure out why one couldn't apply the universal property to an arbitrary element of $End(M)$ (which leads to a contradiction using additive but not linear functions) before remembering that implicit in the typical statement of the universal property is that $S$ must be commutative. This seemed like the best way to resolve this, but again I tend not to trust my own work.